# From where RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies in JAD file come?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I wanted to know from where the values for `RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies` parameter are populated in Jad file of a Blackberry project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is done by RIM's RAPC tool.  You invoke this when you do a build from the JDE or from the Eclipse JDE Plugin.  You can also invoke this from the command line, or using something like bb-ant-tools.

RAPC does a bunch of things - compiling .java files to bytecode (using javac), doing preverification (like sun's WTK), doing some obfuscation/packing/optimization on your bytecode (stripping out unused bits of code, etc), and figuring out what dependencies your .cod will have.

Are you having specific problems with the module dependencies?

Comment: Thanks Anthony,for nice explanation.
Yes,I am facing problem,for which actually I have posted a different question also.
Still I am stucked in the issue.
It is adding net_rim_xml_org,whenever I upload application on phone,it says above file is missing.
The application works fine on Pearl 8100 simulator.
What can be done?

Comment: I think I saw your other question - I've only seen this as a result of compiling with a newer version of the JDE than the OS of your device.  The Pearl initially shipped with the 4.2.1 OS.  If you're building with a 4.3 or later JDE (or Eclipse Plug-in) you'll be able to load the app onto the device, but you'll get this error.  Get the 4.2.1 JDE or the 4.2.1 component pack for the Eclipse Plug-in and recompile.

Comment: Hello Anthony,
I tried installing 4.2.1 component pack for Eclipse.
After installation also I am not getting 4.2.1 in the list of installed components.Only the previous version 4.5.0 is displayed.
How do I get 4.2.1 in component's list?
It will be good if I get a standard process of installing component pack,as I may be missing something.

Comment: I've always installed using the .zip files (couldn't get the update site to work).  Download the zip, go to Help->Software Updates, click on Available Software and then Add Site and click Archive, and select the zip file.